# Ideas for securing decorative trim to brick

Tags: brick, fastener

I have what looks like a 10" x 3/4 board with some crown trim attached to the brick above my garage.  It is currently attached with square cut masonry nails, and part of it is loose.

[image: Trim over garage]

I'd like to remove it to repair some rotted crown and prep and paint, and I'm looking for good ways to reattach it so it can be easily removed in the future.  Ideally without visible fasteners on the front edge.

The trim is as long as the two car garage, so its a bit awkward to work with.

The masonry nails are out, Tapcon screws are my usual goto, but don't lend themselves to repeated removal and have bright blue heads.  Exterior paint would also gum up the threads.  Some type of wooden cleat behind it would still have to be painted and maintained.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider putting small right-angle brackets on top of the trim, mounted into the brick using Tapcon screws, and then screw the other part of the bracket into the crown. You may also want to add in just a couple screws of some kind along the bottom just to hold the crown closer to the garage door if there is a slight gap.

Comment: Gary, please follow up with this post. Abandoned questions are ugly. Delete it if you don't intend to do so.

Comment: I do intend to at some point, but not there yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only and specifically asking about the crown, I'd use screws from above. Stainless or coated exterior screws, properly piloted and countersunk, would hold very well. You could use silicone or construction adhesive behind the lower edge of the crown to keep it snug, too.

This all assumes that the cap is securely fastened to the one-by attached to the wall, of course. It's also possible that you have a 1x6 with crown attached to the top edge, leaving a void under the cap. That would require new fasteners into the masonry. I'd then use trim-head screws and plastic plug anchors in 1/4" holes. They can be easily filled with wood putty before painting.

If your question is broader in scope than that, please revise to clarify.

Comment: The plate, cap and crown is all assembled together and then nailed to the brick.  I'm looking for a way to attach the assembly as a whole to the wall, in a somewhat removable way.

Comment: Ah. Consider keyhole mounts. They'd need to be mortised in, but they're pretty slick.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about a keyhole, but worried about the precision necessary with at least 4 holes and dealing with brick.  It's a contender.

Comment: Yeah, that crossed my mind, too. I'd put the anchors and screws in the brick, then use them to mark the trim precisely.

Comment: I’d opt for a secure water tight mount rather than loosely installed fit that allows moisture to lay between the trim and the brick. You’ll be replacing the trim too often.

Comment: Maybe, but it's difficult to truly seal against something so porous and rough. The masonry is going to be perpetually damp behind the wood anyway, so it may be better to let a bit of air flow.